# In Express JS does app.listen need to be at the end of the file?

Tags: node.js, express

In most tutorials using Express JS the app.listen function is always added at the end of the file. I want to understand if this is essential as all middleware is run in sequence.

Most examples show:

```
const express = require('express)
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Test')
}

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server running on port 3000')
}
```

Is there any reason this shouldn't be done:

```
const express = require('express)
const app = express()

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server running on port 3000')
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Test')
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I worked out the answer to this, in case anyone goes looking for it.

app.listen is effectively a wrapper function that calls `HTTP.createServer`.

From what I can understand `createServer` sets up an event listener on the event loop. When the operating system receives a HTTP request on the particular port being listened to, such as port 80, the req is processed by express.

Since `createServer` is an asynchronous operation it gets executed in the event loop once the main program is executed. Therefore it doesn't matter where this code is placed. It is at the end in most examples as a standard rather than technical requirements.

Comment: that's only true in examples where there's no other asynchronous code being run.  if in order to add routes you need to connect to a database or fetch some external resource, you'd better do things in the right order or else it's possible for HTTP requests to be received before your app's routes are configured.

Comment: (though "the right order" does not necessarily mean "put `app.listen` at the end of the file".)